# Job Offer Switch

Tags: hiring-process, hiring

I have completed 2 interviews for a position selling furniture. The second interview was with the person doing the hiring and she seemed really positive about me getting the job. Today I was called and asked if I would be OK working in the warehouse/delivery for about 3 days a week and selling for just 2 days. Looked on the net and sure enough they have had an open position for a Delivery driver longer than the sales position. I really do not want to work in the warehouse/driver/delivery job, but I agreed to do an interview with the supervisor of that position tomorrow. How do I handle this.

Comment: what do you want to happen? i'm assuming you only want the sales job? do you need the job come what may, or can you keep looking for a different role? do you want to instead do 3 days sales, 2 days delivery? you need to know what your bare minimum is, and then stick to that.

Comment: Are you asking (a) what choice we would recommend you make (which would be off topic), (b) how to decline working in the warehouse (even if this costs you the job) or (c) how to politely indicate that you'd *prefer* not to work in the warehouse (but you'd still take the job if that's required) or something else?

Comment: do you have a truck licence? If you don't then your job will be muscle loading and unloading

Comment: @paparazzo yeah, still have to do the loading, but at least you get to drive a truck which is always fun. Forklift is pretty cool as well

Comment: In my experience, this means you'd be a full-time warehouse and delivery guy, with vague promises of being in sales as requested.

Answer (score 7):

You know what this smells like? This smells like the person who needs to hire a salesman has no political power in the company compared to the person who wants to hire a delivery driver.

I would not even be surprised to learn that the hiring person has been yelled at for trying to fill the sales position before the warehouse/delivery position is filled.

You probably don't want to be either a driver or a salesman in that company. You certainly do not want to devote three days a week of your valuable sales department time to driving a truck.

Tell the company that you are a salesman and not a truck driver. There is no skill set overlap between those two jobs.

Comment: Working in the warehouse/delivery is not truck driver.

Comment: Yeah. Unless equipment is involved, working in the warehoue is BELOW working as truck driver. How comes they od not need sales people ;)

Comment: @paparazzo: "open position for a Delivery driver" appears in the original question.